# Definition of `equivalent systems of linear differential equations'

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm reading F.Beukers' `Notes on differential equations and
hypergeometric functions', and I can't work out the details of something that seems obviously true.

We have a field $K$ endowed with a differential $\partial$ and system of $n$ linear differential equations
$$
\partial \mathbf{y} = A\mathbf{y}.
$$
Then they say that if $S$ is an invertible $n \times n$ matrix $S$ with coefficients in $K$ then `exchanging $\mathbf y$ for $S \mathbf{y}$' we get the system
$$
\partial \mathbf{y} = (S^{-1}AS + S \partial S)\mathbf{y}.
$$

My problem is that I can't get to this system, and I'd really appreciate it if someone could derive this for me.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a typo in the resulting expression?

Comment: Yeah, I guess it must be that, but it's so early on in the text (and seems like such a key concept) I assumed they would get it right! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For clarity, use a new variable ${\bf z}$ such that ${\bf y} = S {\bf z}$.
With this substitution, and 
using the product rule (see definition of derivation),  your first system becomes
$$ (\partial S) {\bf z} + S \partial {\bf z} = \partial (S {\bf z}) = A S {\bf z} $$
Multiply on the left by $S^{-1}$ and it's
$$ \partial {\bf z} = S^{-1} A S {\bf z} - S^{-1} (\partial S) {\bf z}
= \left(S^{-1} A S  - S^{-1} \partial S\right){\bf z}$$
I think your formula has a wrong sign and a missing ${}^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks, the formula must be wrong!